# Unit test React Native app that uses Native Modules with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

I'm trying to test my React Native app with Jest. My app uses a few Native Modules and I can't even run the initial test.

My app uses the component `react-native-camera` that has native dependencies.

The initial test:

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import Index from '../index.ios.js';

// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(
    <Index />
  );
});
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

> FAIL  `__tests__/index.android.js`
>       ● Test suite failed to run
>
> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Aspect' of undefined
>
>   at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-camera/index.js:250:78)
> ```

How can I bypass this type of error causes by native modules? Shallow rendering or similar?

I use RN 0.39.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's described in the Jest docs for react-native now:

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react-native.html#transformignorepatterns-customization

> The transformIgnorePatterns option can be used to whitelist or blacklist files from being transformed with babel. Many react-native npm modules unfortunately don't pre-compile their source code before publishing.
>
> By default the jest-react-native preset only processes the project's own source files and react-native. If you have npm dependencies that have to be transformed you can customize this configuration option by whitelisting modules other than react-native:

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "node_modules/(?!react-native|my-project|react-native-button)/"
]
```

There is also an issue on github within the react-native project that discusses this issue: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2382

Hope this helps